# Как выделить пункт меню активной страницы

Tags: php, javascript

киньте пожалуйста ссылку с уроком где рассказывают как выделить пункт меню активной страницы с помощью javascript, php.

Ну или приведите пример тут

за ранее спасибо

**P.S** меню  у меня в шапке которая находиться в отдельном файле header.php который подключён ко всем страницам

Comment: Добавьте класс к ссылке, которая должна быть активной

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите именно выделить пункт меню, как выделение текста, или нажать на него мышкой. Или навести мышкой например? Если именно выделение, то вот: http://learn.javascript.ru/vydelenie-range-textrange-i-selection

Еще библиотечка есть для работы с выделениями https://code.google.com/p/rangy/

А если сэмулировать клик или наведение мыши например, то все гораздо проще

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто с использованием библиотеки jQuery: вы просто находите на странице ссылку, атрибут href которой равен window.location.pathname и добавляете к этой ссылки какой-то класс или стиль, чтобы выделить её:

```
$('.menu a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active_menu');
```